# Project Doesn't Load With Elmish-React

Tags: html, f#, fable-f#, elmish

I have a simple elmish react project directly from the template and when I run it it loads the public index.html page but nothing else and stucks eternely loading (I presume) the bundle.js from the webpack

I picked the Fable template added the Fable.Elmish.React(nuget), react(npm) and react-dom(npm) packages

App.fs

```ml
module App

open Fable.React
open Fable.React.Props
open Elmish
open Elmish.React
open Elmish.ReactNative

type Model = Empty

type Msg = NOP

let init () = Empty, Cmd.ofMsg NOP

let update msg model = 
  match msg with
    NOP -> model, Cmd.ofMsg NOP

let view model dispatch = 
  div [] [
    h1 [] [str "Hello, world!"]
  ]

Program.mkProgram init update view
|> Program.withReactBatched "container"
|> Program.run
```

Index.html

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>TGG</title>
  <meta http-equiv='Content-Type' content='text/html; charset=utf-8'>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <script defer src="bundle.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
  <div class="container">
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up finding the answer myself

The problem was on the init function

```fs
let init () = Empty, Cmd.ofMsg NOP
```

There were two problems, the first being that the `Empty` was refering to a HTML element instead of the mock model i was using to  set everything up, the other that is a lesser problem was the part `Cmd.ofMsg NOP` I should be using `Cmd.none` instead